# Modifying the envelope once created on docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Can we modify the envelope once created ?(Draft and Sent both the status). If possible, can you point me to the documentation for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can modify an "in-process" Envelope, but only certain properties of an existing Envelope can be changed.  I'd suggest that you search the table of contents in the **DocuSign REST API guide** (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf) for the word "modify" -- that will show you (at a glance) the types of things that can be modified.  For example, you'll see that these types of things can be modified on an existing Envelope:

- envelope custom fields (p141)
- custom document fields (p154)
- email setting overrides (p162)
- recipient information (p171)
- recipient tabs (p178)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does answer my question. One more - Can we add templates to in progress envelope(sent status).

Comment: No, I don't believe it's possible to add Templates to an in-progress (sent) Envelope. If you need to add templates, you'd need to: 1) void the original Envelope, and 2) create/send the new Envelope that contains all necessary docs/templates.  [Please mark this answer as 'accepted' so that others may benefit from the info in the future...thanks!]